# Flutter crashes on Android when canceling (image_picker) activity

Tags: android, flutter, dart

There are a lot of similar questions here, but none answers the problem.

When using image_picker, barcode_scanner or other plugins which open their own activities everything works well until I use either the "cancel" button or the "back"-Button. My app crashes as soon as I hit the cancel-button with the following error log:
(I used image_cropper to show this error, but image_picker and barcode_scanner create similar errors)

```
  Croppfile
D/AndroidRuntime(31882): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(31882): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31882): Process: ch.app.appcrossplatform, PID: 31882
E/AndroidRuntime(31882): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=69, result=0, data=null} to activity {ch.app.appcrossplatform/ch.app.appcrossplatform.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5230)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5271)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at cachet.plugins.health.HealthPlugin.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onActivityResult(FlutterFragment.java:699)
E/AndroidRuntime(31882):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterFragmentActivity.java:510)
```

This is the Code when using the cropper:

```
  croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: pickedFile.path,
        cropStyle: CropStyle.rectangle,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        ],
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Dokument zuschneiden',
            toolbarColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 110, 246),
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
          minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
          title: "Dokument hinzufügen",
          doneButtonTitle: "Fertig",
          cancelButtonTitle: "Abbrechen",
        ));
        print("Croppfile");
        if(croppedFile == null) return;
```

This is my Main-Activity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `image_picker` are you using ?

Comment: I'm using ^0.6.7+2. But I don't think it's the plugins fault, since there are at least three plugins which crash when I hit the cancel-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error myself, it was actually in another repository I used: The health Plugin can't handle these "null"-results: https://pub.dev/packages/health.
I didn't think another plugin can cause such results.

Relevant issue in the health package: https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/88

Since other Activities cause onAcitivityResult to run, the health plugin causes the crash